# For Each loop for multiple customer id's within MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an existing table which hold 1000's of records. I need to update each record depending on the customer id and a date field associated with it.

Basically so i can put an ordered number beside each date depending on the order of the dates.

I think I need to use two 'for each' loops to get this done. I.E.

```
For Each Customer ID in tblCustomers

'gather all records for that customer and get all dates in order from each record via recordset?

    For Each Date 
    newfield = newfield+ 1
    end loop

end loop
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to figure this out?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of update are you doing? i.e. why do you need to be using a recordset versus an update query? Are all these records being updated uniformly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
Dim rstCustomers As DAO.Recordset
Set rstCustomers = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomers GROUP BY CustomerID")
If rstCustomers.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rstCustomers.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstCustomers.EOF
        Dim rstRecords As DAO.Recordset
        Set rstRecords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT RecordDate, OrderField FROM tblRecords WHERE CustomerID = " & rstCustomers!CustomerID & " ORDER BY RecordDate")
        If rstRecords.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Dim iCount as Integer
            iCount = 1
            rstRecords.MoveFirst
            Do Until rstRecords.EOF
                rstRecords.Edit
                   rstRecords!OrderField = iCount
                rstRecords.Update

                iCount = iCount + 1
                rstRecords.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        rstRecords.Close
        Set rstRecords = Nothing

        rstCustomers.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rstCustomers.Close
Set rstCustomers = Nothing
```

Comment: Great, going through this now, when you mentioned rstRecords.Edit, did you mean rstRecords.EditMode?

Comment: No, `.Edit` should put the current record in the recordset into 'edit mode' so that you can change values. Then the `.Update` line updates the actual record in the table

Comment: Ok, everty time I run the code, it throws up an error saying "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" and highlights the code rstRecords.Edit. Do you know what this could mean?

Comment: Can you make sure it's using DAO, by changing the lines `Dim rst... As Recordset` to `Dim rst... As DAO.Recordset` to see if that helps?

Comment: I added, in bold, into the rstRecords SQL to 'SELECT RecordDate, **OrderField**' etc   Seems to work now! unreal! Thanks a million!

Comment: Sorry, yeah I forgot to include that field. The field names were really just to give you an idea but glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Loop records with using [Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177501%28v=office.12%29.aspx)